# nodejs - How to test whether remote socket is open

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am creating a socket pass through inspector.

Basically, I start up a socket server (`net.createServer`) and a socket client (`net.connect`). For testing purposes, I do not have a endpoint socket waiting.

I want test whether the endpoint socket is available. If not, nodejs should wait until socket is available.

```
var net = require('net');
var inbound = net.createServer();
var outbound = net.connect({
    port: 8193
});

inbound.listen(8192, function () { //'listening' listener
    address = inbound.address();
    console.log('Server started on %j', address);
});

inbound.on('connection', function (insock, outbound) {
    console.log('CONNECTED ' + insock.remoteAddress + ':' + insock.remotePort);
    insock.on('data', function (data, outbound) {
        outbound.write(data);
        console.log('DATA ' + data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to test whether any resource is available is to try to use it. Pre-testing is liable to a number of objections:

1. If it tests something different from the actual usage, it may yield an incorrect answer.
2. If it tests the same things as the actual usage it is merely wastefully redundant.
3. The situation may change between the test and the usage.

Comment: I'm definitely testing it but i'm not sure how to recover the node.js app when the remote port is not open. Nodejs throws a "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED"

Comment: That's the same thing that would happen if you just tried to use it. Whatever the solution to this is, it's the same solution to the 'try to use it' case. You don't need to write the same code twice.

Comment: Use `outbound.on('error', ...)` to catch those errors instead of having Node crash on them.

Comment: @robertklep - Thanks! I've added **bold** `outbound.on('error', function(data){ 'console.log('Error - ' + data);` It shows the error message but i'm not sure how to make nodejs recover and continue. Right now, it crashes out to command line.

Comment: @user2135737 not sure why; I created a simple [gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5627971) to demonstrate how to check and, if an error occurs, retry after a bit (it uses your variable naming, hope that's not too confusing :)

Comment: @robertklep, This works! I had the `outbound.on('error...` outside the `inbound.on('connection', function (insock, outbound) {
    console.log('CONNECTED ' + insock.remoteAddress + ':' + insock.remotePort);` line. now i know how it is meant to work.